# Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been trying to get the Media element to work in PhoneGap when deploying to Android. Here's what I did so far:

**Download and install the below:**

Java (Version 7 Update 25)
http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Java SE Development Kit 7u25 (64 bit)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Ant (1.9.2)
http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/

NodeJS (v0.10.18 64 bit)
http://nodejs.org/

Android SDK (ADT Bundle for Windows) 64 bit - version 2013-07-29
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Installation folder: E:\PhoneDev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729

**Set environment variables:**

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7  
ANT_HOME = E:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.2  
NODEJS = E:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
```

**Verify that the following paths are added to the PATH Environment variable (separated by semi-colons):**

```
E:\PhoneDev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platform-tools  
E:\PhoneDev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools  
%ANT_HOME%\bin  
%NODEJS%  
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

**Install PhoneGap (Right now it's version 3.0.0):**

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

**Create phonegap app:**

```
phonegap create media-app
```

**Build phonegap app:**

```
cd media-app
phonegap local build android
```

**Add in media-app\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml:**

```
<feature name="Media">  
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />  
</feature>
```

**Add in platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Replace the contents of media-app\www\index.html with the "Full Example" on the following page:**
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

**Run phonegap app in emulator:**

```
media-app\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat
```

The application runs correctly, but when I try to play a sound I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined at  
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

I also tried doing the same thing from Eclipse which is bundled with the Android SDK. I created an AVD and ran the application from Eclipse. I get the same error.
I’ve been trying to understand what the problem is for a while. If someone can shed some light on this problem I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Well what's in the "index.html" file?

Comment: Search for "Full Example" on this page: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 3.0, PhoneGap implements device-level APIs as plugins. Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The [Command-line Interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface), to add or remove this feature for a project:

You need to add the media plugin to your project -

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
```

Run that above command within the project's directory and you should be set.

Comment: I added the plugin with the command line :
    cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
But it still does'nt work :(

Comment: As of phonegap **5.2.0**, `phonegap local` command is deprecated