# Media is not defined - How do I enable Media in a PhoneGap app in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm developing an application using PhoneGap in Eclipse and whenever I use the Media object I get an exception on this line:

```
var test = new Media("/android_asset/www/sound/music/Weird.mp3", null, null, null);
```

> 12-31 13:52:56.775: E/Web Console(3688): Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   Media is not defined:25

This exception is, [supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643255/uncaught-referenceerror-media-is-not-defined), due to the fact that I haven't implemented the Media plugin. I just upgraded from 2.9 to 3.3 so there were some changes with the new plugin-system that I haven't used before.

I tried to follow the instructions in [the PhoneGap Media documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) but it kept refering to the use of their Command Line Interface. I'm working in Eclipse and I have created the entire project in eclipse, built the Cordova-3.3.0.jar file myself and then added it to the project. Everything works fine up until the use of the Media object.

Anyone have any idea how to add support for Media to a PhoneGap 3.3.0 project? Can I use the CLI on a project created in Eclipse?

I tried to just add support for it by adding the following to my **res/xml/config.xml** file:

```
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
```

and then adding the proper permissions in my **AndroidManifest** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but that didn't work very well either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: link might help : http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/media-sample-using-phonegap

Comment: Kamlesh Arya: I can't see how that article is going to help me. My problem is that I can't even use the Media object to start with.

Comment: If you didn't use the command line to install the plugin, do you have the .java files for the plugin in, src/org/apache/cordova/media ?  Actually I am a little confused.  My config.xml file like the cordova docs has the package at: org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler  Clearly a little different than yours.

Comment: You should also have a Media.js file in assets/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/www along with an entry for that file in the assets/www/cordova_plugins.js file {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/www/Media.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.media.Media",
        "clobbers": [
            "window.Media"
        ]
    }

Comment: I do not have a media.java in src/org/apache/cordova/media. The URL org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler  was what I found in the Media object documentation here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. The problem was that I created my Eclipse project using only the **Cordova-3.3.0.jar** file I had manually built from the source. I should've just created the project using the Command Line Interface as the manual clearly states, **added the Media (also through the CLI)** and then **imported the entire project into Eclipse using File => New => Other => Android from Existing Source**.

I got it working now doing it as I described above, hopefully this might help someone some day :P

Comment: Even i am facing this same error. Media is undefined. I have already added the media plugin through CLI. How did you resolve this issue?